# Run thread 1 every x seconds; every y seconds, wait for thread 1 to finish and run thread 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My goal is to:

- run thread 1 every x seconds
- every y seconds, wait for thread 1 to finish, pause thread 1, run thread 2
- repeat

Right now when I run thread_crawl() and thread_extract() concurrently, thread_extract only throws an error when thread_crawl is in the middle of running since it uses its files.

This is my current code that runs both threads concurrently.

```py
def thread_crawl():
    while True:
        crawl(' ', path)
        time.sleep(2)


def thread_extract():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        extract(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(path + 'archive_dict.pkl'):  # performs initial crawl to build archive_dict.pkl (required by article_extractor.py)
        crawl(' ', path)
    crawler = threading.Thread(target=thread_crawl)
    extractor = threading.Thread(target=thread_extract)
    crawler.start()
    extractor.start()
```

Comment: If the two threads are alternating, why not combine them into one worker thread that calls `crawl()` then calls `extract()` alternately in a loop?

Comment: I want to have the option to turn extract() off at anytime and only have crawl() running.

Comment: That still seems doable with one worker.. just add a conditional `if should_extract: extract()`. Can you clarify your program requirements further? The design you're proposing feels unnecessary (see [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: You're right. Now I feel stupid haha